# iphone sqlite problem: "out of memory" on sqlite3_prepare_v2

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm wondering if someone can help me understand what is wrong with this block of code.  I never get past the sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement and the debugger says :

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'out of memory''

```
    static sqlite3 *database = nil;
sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;

if(addStmt == nil) {
    NSLog(@"About to add start time...\n");
    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO games_played(start) VALUES(?)";     
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    NSLog(@"add statement created successfully!\n");
}
NSLog(@"About to bind start time...\n");
sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, @"start time", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Answer (score 26):

I never opened the database...I think thats the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I had this problem too :)

Comment: I've noticed I allways get "out of memory" on any SQL syntax error, perhaps this is a bug in sqlite3 with sqlite3_errmsg?

Answer (score 11):

It is not a bug, the problem is you never open the database. For example:

```
if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Comment: To be clear you have to do this

sqliteStatusCode = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &tracksDB);

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem, and solved it by reset the database for the sqlite statement.